# Featherjs authentication: Login using OTP

Tags: feathersjs, feathers-authentication

I'm using local strategy for authentication purpose using featherjs framework.

Besides username and password auth mechanism, client wants to login using username and OTP.
Can someone provide me hint, how can I achieve this?
I've studied existing framework featherjs-authentication, I could not understand how can I extend it to support this need.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem using package [feathers-authentication-custom](https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-authentication-custom)

It gives you a hook wherein you can add your auth verifier. In my case, I keep OTP associated with user id. When user calls authenticate with custom strategy, the verifier middleware gets called. Here I verify the OTP and pass back the token to the client.